# I cant create view when declare table on it

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This code show remind tools in my ware but on my program I used EF and now 
I want to create view and use it  in C#

```
CREATE VIEW s AS
(
DECLARE @ta AS TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(30),qty INT,so INT,tar INT) 
INSERT INTO @ta 
SELECT p.Name,t.Qty,t.Source,t.target FROM dbo.Products p
JOIN dbo.TradeOff t ON t.ProductId = p.ProductID 
DECLARE @source AS TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(30),qty INT,so INT) 
DECLARE @tar AS TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(30),qty INT,tar INT) 

INSERT INTO @source 
SELECT t1.NAME,SUM(t1.qty),t1.so  FROM @ta t1
GROUP BY t1.so,t1.NAME

INSERT INTO @tar 
SELECT t1.NAME,SUM(t1.qty),t1.tar  FROM @ta t1

GROUP BY t1.tar,t1.NAME

SELECT s.NAME,ISNULL(t.Qty,0 )-ISNULL(s.qty,0),ISNULL(t.tar,s.so) FROM @tar t 
RIGHT JOIN @source s ON s.so=t.tar AND s.NAME=t.NAME 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `table variable` inside a `view`. Try this instead

```
CREATE VIEW s
AS
  SELECT s.NAME,
         Isnull(t.Qty, 0) - Isnull(s.qty, 0),
         Isnull(t.tar, s.so)
  FROM   (SELECT t1.NAME,
                 Sum(t1.qty),
                 t1.tar
          FROM   (SELECT p.NAME,
                         t.Qty,
                         t.Source,
                         t.target
                  FROM   dbo.Products p
                         JOIN dbo.TradeOff t
                           ON t.ProductId = p.ProductID) t1
          GROUP  BY t1.tar,
                    t1.NAME) t
         RIGHT JOIN (SELECT t1.NAME,
                            Sum(t1.qty),
                            t1.so
                     FROM   (SELECT p.NAME,
                                    t.Qty,
                                    t.Source,
                                    t.target
                             FROM   dbo.Products p
                                    JOIN dbo.TradeOff t
                                      ON t.ProductId = p.ProductID) t1
                     GROUP  BY t1.so,
                               t1.NAME) s
                 ON s.so = t.tar
                    AND s.NAME = t.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use table variables you can use a stored procedure to table valued functions to achieve this however these are slower then views and depending on where you want to use the data would determine which solution best fits your requirements